# QTP - dynamically pass browser/page title changes for web application?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp

I need some help while working on logout,i want to prepare unique logout function but here i'm facing problem like while working with applications i've different modules as per keyword driven it will work.

I want to click on Logout link irrespective of the page title and i want to pass dynamically changing page name and titles to below code.

```
pageTitleName = Browser("CreationTime:=0").Page("title:=.*").GetROProperty("title")
Print pageTitleName
Browser("pageTitleName").Page("pageTitleName").Link("name:=Logout").Click
```

I'm getting error that object is not created ,please provide how to achieve this to

```
Browser("whatever").Page("whatever")......etc
```

Comment: You could also consider setting the title property in the OR to a regular expression value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pageTitleName = Browser("CreationTime:=0").Page("title:=.*").GetROProperty("title")
Print pageTitleName
Browser("pageTitleName").Page("pageTitleName").Link("name:=Logout").Click

Too me it looks like, in the first line you are using descriptive programming for object & reading the page title.
in the second line you are directly using the property as if the object exists in OR. You are mixing the object identification part here.

you can modify the second line as

Browser("title:="&pageTitleName).Page("title:="&pageTitleName).Link("name:=Logout").Click

Comment: Yes,it is working fine and please help ,i want to create unique function for this and call it to each and every function,please help

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called SetTOProperty for your requirement. I assume you are using title property for browser and page both and both are in repository.

Use the code like below...

```
Browser("browser"). SetTOProperty ("title"," yourdynamictitle")
Browser("browser").Page("page"). SetTOProperty ("title"," yourdynamictitle")

Browser("browser").Page("page").Link("LogOut").Click
```

SetTOProperty sets the specified object property value runtime.

Else, if you are using inline descriptive, use the below code

```
Browser("title:=" & strBrowserTitle).Page("title:=" & strPageTitle).Link("name:=LogOut").Click
```

Where strBrowserTitle, strPageTitle are string variables containing title values of browser and page respectively